# Create text_box with Entry for a list - tkinter Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, textbox, tkinter-entry

I have a list `out_list = ["item1",item2","item3",....]` which I am trying to add text_box and `Entry` for each item as the following:

[image]

But when I'm trying to get from the text box, `text_box.get("1.0",'end-1c')`, I am getting all of the list as one string.

Thanks for the help!

```
        for i in range(0,len(out_list)):
            text_box.window_create(text_box.index("end"), window=tk.Button(text_box, text="Copy Variable",command=buttonClick))
            text_box.window_create(text_box.index("end"), window=tk.Entry(text_box, text=str(out_list[i])))
            text_box.window_create(text_box.index("end"),text_box.insert(END, out_list[i]), window=text_box_value)
        text_box.insert(END,'\n')  # adds text to text box
```

Comment: `text1_id = text_box.window_create(..)` and now you can access first textbox using `text1_id`

Comment: or maybe you should first create `entry_1 = tk.Entry(..)` and keep it on list - to have access to this Entry, or to use `command=lambda:buttonClick(entry_1)`

Comment: or maybe you should use `Frame` to group elements `Button`, `Entry`, `text` and create own widget (with all needed functions for single row) and use this widget in `for`-loop

Comment: instead of `for i in range(0,len(out_list))` you could learn to use `for item in out_list:`

Answer (score 1):

You should first create `Entry`

```
entry = tk.Entry(text_box)
entry.insert("end", item)
```

and later you could use it in

```
command=lambda:button_click(entry))
```

but it is inside `for`-loop and `lambda` doesn't copy value from `entry` to code `button_click(entry)` so it keeps only reference to `entry` and this `entry` is changing in loop - and finally all lambda has reference to the same variable which has last value. You have to use extra variable to copy object.

```
command=lambda x=entry:button_click(x))
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` not preferred

# --- functions --- (PEP8: lower_case_names)

def button_click(entry):
    print('ENTRY:', entry.get())

# --- main ---

out_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", ]  # PEP8: spaces after comma

root = tk.Tk()

text_box = tk.Text(root)
text_box.pack()

for item in out_list:
    print(item)
    
    entry = tk.Entry(text_box)
    entry.insert("end", item)
    
    button = tk.Button(text_box, text="Copy Variable", command=lambda x=entry:button_click(x))
    
    text_box.window_create(text_box.index("end"), window=button)
    text_box.window_create(text_box.index("end"), window=entry)
    #text_box.window_create(text_box.index("end"), text_box.insert('end', item), window=text_box_value)
    text_box.insert("end", item)
    text_box.insert("end", '\n')  # adds text to text box

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You could also use `Frame` to build own widget with `Button`, `Entry`, `Label` and `button_click` and later use this widget.

It can be simpler to add or hide widget.

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` not preferred

# --- classes --- (PEP8: CamelCaseNames) 

class MyWidget(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, text, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
               
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Copy Variable", command=self.button_click)
        self.button.pack(side="left")
    
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.insert("end", text)
        self.entry.pack(side="left")
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=text)
        self.label.pack(side="left")
        
    def button_click(self):
        print('ENTRY:', self.entry.get())
        #self.button["text"] = self.entry.get()
    
# --- functions --- (PEP8: lower_case_names)

def copy_all_variables():
    for widget in all_widgets:
        print(widget.entry.get())
        #widget.button_copy()

def add_widget():
    item = "item" + str(len(all_widgets)+1)
    widget = MyWidget(frame_widget, text=item)
    widget.pack(fill='x')
    all_widgets.append(widget)

def remove_widget():
    if all_widgets:
        all_widgets[-1].destroy()
        del all_widgets[-1]

# --- main ---

out_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", ]  # PEP8: spaces after comma

root = tk.Tk()

# - version 1 -

tk.Label(root, text="Text Box + window_create()", bg="#8080ff").pack(fill='x', expand=True)

text_box = tk.Text(root)
text_box.pack()

all_widgets_1 = []

for item in out_list:
    widget = MyWidget(text_box, text=item)
    text_box.window_create(text_box.index("end"), window=widget)
    text_box.insert("end", '\n')  # adds text to text box
    all_widgets_1.append(widget)

# - version 2 -

tk.Label(root, text="Frame + pack()", bg="#8080ff").pack(fill='x', expand=True)

all_widgets = []

frame_widget = tk.Frame(root)
frame_widget.pack(fill='x')

for item in out_list:
    widget = MyWidget(frame_widget, text=item)
    widget.pack(fill='x')
    all_widgets.append(widget)
   
frame_buttons = tk.Frame(root)
frame_buttons.pack()   

button_copy = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text="Copy All Variables", command=copy_all_variables)
button_copy.pack(side="left")

button_add = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text="Add Widget", command=add_widget)
button_add.pack(side="left")

button_remove = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text="Remove Widget", command=remove_widget)
button_remove.pack(side="left")

# - 

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

And when you put `Button` and `Entry` directly to `Text` then you can write text between widgets.

[image]

Comment: Hi furas, that's indeed what I meant, works perfect,
I added a search to that list, but I am trying to "clean" the widgets once a updated list.
I have tried the following:
"        for label in root.pack_slaves():
            if label.pack_fo
            print(label)
            label.destroy()"

Comment: I don't know if I understand example code. if you mean to remove text from all labels then assing empty string - `for widget in all_widgets: widget.label["text"] = ""`. If you mean to remove all  widgets then `for widget in all_widgets: widget.destroy()` and `all_widgets = []`.

Comment: i noticed i inserted the wrong code - without buttons `Add Widget` and `Remove Widget` - but I put image with these buttons. Now code has these buttons.